# Analytics data schema (at github) : dimension & measure

Tags: database, google-analytics, schema, analytics

I was following along an article on [analytics at github](http://johnnunemaker.com/analytics-at-github/), and like to know more about the data schema (for analytics). It mentions `We split out payload into dimensions (flat map of string keys and values) and measures (flat map of string keys and integer values)`, and gave a snippet. Is there any formal term for this structure to search for? How dimension and measure related? How they use together to aggregate data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**bsr**, I would suggest using the [dimension / metric reference tool](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) provided by Google that shows the relationships between various dimensions and metrics.

Also, [Avinash Kaushik wrote a very interesting article](http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/hits-sessions-metrics-dimensions-web-analytics/) on using proper combinations of various dimensions/metrics of different scope (in GA there is 3 of them: hit, session, user).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Petr. Those are valuable resources to understand the terminology.